# Why don't non-Changelings die when killed in the Dreaming, but get kicked out into the Umbra instead?

Tags: world-of-darkness, character-death, changeling, changeling-the-dreaming

Inspired by this post: [What happens when a Changeling dies in the Dreaming?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/181519/what-happens-when-a-changeling-dies-in-the-dreaming/)

So, yes, Changelings killed *in* the Dreaming (as opposed to just by chimerical damage in the mortal world) are killed for good, the human body dies as well. Part of the explanation is that all glamour counts as Wyrd in the Dreaming, so the character is killed on both levels.

However, why is it then enchanted mortals and other non-Changelings do not die, but are merely disenchanted and dropped somewhere in the Umbra? (This is explicitly stated in Dreams and Nightmares, p. 31.) As also stated there, yes, this might be *as bad as dying* for some of them, i.e. might end up getting them killed soon in some inhospitable umbral plane - but it's still way different than a simple "you're dead".

I'm not talking about whether it's fair or not in metagame terms - I simply want to understand the in-universe logic. If all glamour is Wyrd in the Dreaming, why won't a human's (vampire's, werewolf's, whosever) body end up just as dead?

Comment: This question bothers me because I can't find any information either way.  I've browsed through CTD20a a few times now can cannot find anything about what happens to mortals (enchanted or otherwise) when they take damage (chimerical or otherwise) in the dreaming.

Comment: I'm mostly using the old WoD with some additions from 20a where convenient, but it seems they simply didn't cover that one well - i.e. didn't think it through well enough. I was hoping that maybe there's something in some related fiction or obscure sourcebook that I haven't read, but nothing so far.

Comment: CTD20a has a section for how to play enchanted mortals, but doesn't talk anything at all about what happens during death.  Seems like a huge oversight.

Comment: Ah, those new kids, they presume the Storyteller won't ever let them die. ;)